# Remove keys from object array and turn values into key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array like the following:

```
data =
   [{'province': 'North', 'level': 1, 'count': 204},
    {'province': 'South', 'level': 1, 'count': 24},
    {'province': 'East', 'level': 1, 'count': 24},
    {'province': 'West', 'level': 1, 'count': 39}];
```

I want to remove the attribute level, and want to make the province value a key, and the count value the value making the **desired output**:

```
result = 
   {'North':204, 'South':24, 'East':24, 'West':39}
```

I have been able to remove the 'level attribute with the following:

```
let test = _.map(data, function(currentObject) {
    return _.pick(currentObject, "province", "count");
  });
```

which gives me:

```
test = 
    [{'province': 'North', 'count': 204},
    {'province': 'South', 'count': 24},
    {'province': 'East', 'count': 24},
    {'province': 'West', 'count': 39}];
```

How can I get to my desired result?

Comment: data.map((e)=> {
 return {[e.province]:e.count}
})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with **[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)**:

```js
let data =[
  {'province': 'North', 'level': 1, 'count': 204},
  {'province': 'South', 'level': 1, 'count': 24},
  {'province': 'East', 'level': 1, 'count': 24},
  {'province': 'West', 'level': 1, 'count': 39}
];

let res = data.reduce((acc, curr) =>
{
    acc[curr.province] = curr.count;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that I understood what the desired out come is, map the data into a new object:

```js
const data =
      [{'province': 'North', 'level': 1, 'count': 204},
       {'province': 'South', 'level': 1, 'count': 24},
       {'province': 'East', 'level': 1, 'count': 24},
       {'province': 'West', 'level': 1, 'count': 39}];

const provinces = data.map(d => ({ [d.province]: d.count }));

console.log(provinces)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very short approach is to map new objects with the wanted property and assign all to a single object.

```js
var data = [{ province: 'North', level: 1, count: 204 }, { province: 'South', level: 1, count: 24 }, { province: 'East', level: 1, count: 24 }, { province: 'West', level: 1, count: 39 }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...data.map(({ province, count }) => ({ [province]: count })));

console.log(result);
```